# Distributed file system for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, distributed

Lately I've been reading up on HDFS (Hadoop) and GFS (Google) and find myself wondering if there are any similar native implementations for windows and/or .NET. A lot of the applications I develop include features to support user generated content, and currently, that means relying on some type of storage service such as Mosso or S3, or resorting to some type of NAS in my server farm. I'm interested in a setup that would allow me to mimic the Mosso or S3 style of storage locally so that my files are automatically stored on multiple machines and have high availability.

Is there anything that serves this need for C# besides Windows' built-in DFS (which requires Active Directory, which isn't running on my server farm)?

Comment: +1 good question, im guessing the answer is no , closest thing i can think of is windows live sync, but it is not a full blown file system

Answer (score 2):

Open AFS, SQL Data Services or just [run Hadoop on windows](http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/)?